# How to get all columns' names from an Oracle table

Tags: java, oracle, metadata

How can I get all columns' names from an Oracle table using Java?
Is there a way to get them from DatabaseMetaData object?

```
DatabaseMetaData myDatabaseMetaData = myConnection.getMetaData();
...
```

I know I can get them using a select statement:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns where table_name='MYTABLE'
```

If it is possible to get them from DatabaseMetaData object, what is the difference between the two methods?

EDIT: Posting working code (thanks for your answers)

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllFields(String tableName) {
    ArrayList<String> allFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        DatabaseMetaData myDatabaseMetaData = myConnection.getMetaData();
        ResultSet columnsResultSet = myDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
        while (columnsResultSet.next()) { allFields.add(columnsResultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME")); }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
    }
    return allFields;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Well the difference between your SQL and the JDBC API is, that the API call is supposed work on all DBMS, whereas the SQL will only work on Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

DatabaseMetaData#getColumns(String, String, String, String)

Your direct SQL call will only work in Oracle, while the DatabaseMetaData method should be database independent.

Answer (score 1):

[DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) is an interface, so it depends all on the JDBC driver implementation. Be shure to use the best and last published one.